# How to check whether a function in dll/lib is extern "C" in windows?

Tags: c++, extern

For example `ObReferenceObjectByName` is defined in `c`, so in c++ should use `extern "C"`

But how can I check this directly in the dll/lib instead of reading docs?

Comment: Why don't you want to read the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the export in Dependency Walker.

Open the DLL, find the function in the middle right pane, and look at the icon.  It will be `C`, `C++`, or `O#` (exported by ordinal only)
For more information, see [Export Function List View](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_export_list_view.htm) in the help file.

Comment: Will it be able to know whether it's c/c++ if the function is exported only by ordinal?

Comment: @kern: That doesn't make any sense. C/C++ exports control the function name (specifically, whether it gets mangled to support overloads), which doesn't exist for ordinal exports.

Comment: how can one know whether it gets mangled to support overloads ?

Comment: C++ supports overloads; C doesn't.  C++ exports are name-mangled.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 4):

Just look at the symbol name in the lib file. If the name has been mangled like C++ does with its names, it should be obvious.